# Backbone.js:how can I cancel the view add parent element to the template

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I know Backbone.js's View object has parameters like `id`, `tagName`, `className`.

```
var DocumentRow = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  className: "document-row",
});
```

It uses these for the insert template's parent element.  When I do not set them, it will add a `<div>` to the template as the template's parent.

But it really annoys me because sometimes I don't need the parent!  All I need I already have in my template, so how can I cancel it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var DocumentRow = Backbone.View.extend({

  el:'#your-element-id' //or class or type

});
```

This states that the view is to be bound to a pre-existing element as specified by the `el` property. Look up the docs at backbonejs.org

Since you already have it in your template just create and bind this view to it "after" the template is created (perhaps in a separate function?)

Comment: :the problem is the parent I have already defined is also need parameter use template ,I don't want separate them

Comment: @hh54188 - okay I'm a bit confused. Could you post some more code actually showing the situation?